# How to filter a displayed JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

I'm trying to make a web application using Outlook API's that allows me to search for a specific Outlook contact by his name.

I've got a little knowledge of javaScript but i never used any API or manipulated JSON files beforehand, so i looked through tutorials to help me, and
I ran into this one : https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/javascript which i followed and succeeded to implement without much trouble.

Briefly, the tutorial allows me to build an app that can display the last 10 emails from the user, or the contact list of this user, which gives something like that : 
[Contacts displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsdLw.png)
Now what i'm trying to do is to filter this display and be able to search something like " give the contacts which name contains the syllable "AG" ".
I tried to understand the code as much as i can and i'm almost sure that i have to modify the function displaying all the contacts.

So what i did is that i pasted it, renamed it but now i'm struggling with the query parameters.

```js
function getUserContacts(emailAddress, callback) {
    getAccessToken(function(accessToken) {
   if (accessToken) {
     // Call the Outlook API
     var callOptions = {
    // Get contacts
    url: apiEndpoint + '/Me/contacts',
    token: accessToken,
    method: 'GET',
    email: emailAddress,
    query: {
      // Limit to the first 100 contacts
      '$top': 100,
      // Only return fields we will use
      '$select': 'GivenName,Surname,EmailAddresses',
      // Sort by given name alphabetically
      '$orderby': 'GivenName ASC'
    }
     }; 
 
     makeApiCall(callOptions, function(result, error) {
    if (error) {
      callback(null, error);
    } else {
      callback(result.value);
    }
     });
   } else {
     var error = { responseText: 'Could not retrieve access token' };
     callback(null, error);
   }
    });
  
  }
```

And that's the moment i get totally lost, i tried adding '$where':GivenName='*AG*' in the query{} section, as well as '$filter':GivenName='*AG*', but neither of them worked. I searched online for an answer but in every one i founded, the JSON file was "available" ( meaning for me that they have,somewhere this kind of code :

`[
  {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298","website":"google222"},
  {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222","website":"google"}
  ]`

But i don't have this type of code anywhere, so i'm wondering if it is possible to do it like i tried to, or if i have to find a way to retrieve the JSON file in order to obtain something like just above ?

I hope i've been clear enough despite my lack of experience in this field, i'd be glad to give some more details/codes if you ask too !

Thanks in advance and have a great day :)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this API but [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#filter-requests) seems to indicate that it only lets you do "equals", "not equals", "greater than", "less than" type searches... I don't see anything like "contains" in there, but I could be wrong. You might try constructing a *eq* search for AG and see if that does it. Worst come to worst you could pull all the contacts and do the filtering on the client side in your JS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'll try to filter with the entire "AG-carto" GivenName, so i tried to write the URL request in Outlook Sandbox [link](https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/), i'm trying with this one that i think is correct :                                    https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts/?&top=100&select=GivenName,Surname,EmailAddresses&orderby=GivenName%20ASC?&filter=GivenName eq 'ag-carto'                                                  But when i try it through the sandbox it gives me all my contacts and not only the ones that should be filtered :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Useless Code and his link i managed to send the right request (error was coming from the fact that filter properties must be listed first in the orderby)  from the outlook sandbox and get the expected answer with this URL:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts?$filter=GivenName eq 'AG-Carto'&$orderby=GivenName ASC&$select=GivenName,Surname,EmailAddresses
```

Now what i'm trying to do is to get my javascript code to send it right.

So i know i have to modify the query{} part of the function, i tried this :

```
                query: {      
              '$filter': 'GivenName eq AG-carto',
              '$orderby': 'GivenName ASC',
              '$select': 'GivenName,Surname,EmailAddresses'
            }
```

But when i run it, i got a bad request error, and i see that the url sent by the js code is this one :

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Me/contacts?%24filter=GivenName+eq+AG-carto&%24orderby=GivenName+ASC&%24select=GivenName%2CSurname%2CEmailAddresses
```

So i'm obviously seeing that they aren't the same, and i have no idea on how to modify the query{} section so that the URL sent by js is the same as my working URL. If anyone could help me on that i'd be grateful !